# Multiple region availability of users in firebase

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, high-availability

I am currently working on SAAS Application, where the world wide users can authenticate to our system.We are in research between AWSCognito and Firebase authentication.I was able to see AWSCognito user pools can be made available across multi-regions by replicating the user pools in needed regions so that the world wide users can authenticate with very low latency.In case of Firebase ,there is an option from multi-region but not suits for my use case.our targeting areas are IND,AUS,US and UK.So, can anyone suggest me to do a proper architecture for this use case ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase Authentication stores user data in a single global pool.

The data is replicated across the worldwide automatically across Google infrastructure, but there is no way for you to control regional shards for your users in Firebase Authentication. So if that is a requirement for your application, you'll need to use another system.

Comment: So, for example if i created a Firebase project in Indian server, the data will replicate across worldwide and users will face same latency, wherever they from right ?

Comment: Not necessarily the same latency, but it's outside of your control where the user data is stored.